# Обновить данные с проверкой их изменения

Tags: c++

Есть переменная `changed`, которая определяет, было ли обновление переменной `data`:

```
const auto new_data = get_new_data();
changed = data != new_data;
data = new_data;
```

Можно ли переписать этот кусок кода проще? Например, без промежуточной переменной `new_data`? Валиден ли следующий вариант или это UB из-за непонятного порядка выполнения?

```
changed = std::exchange(data, get_new_data()) == data;
```

[Проверка правильности обновлений](https://godbolt.org/z/heETs4fcY).

Comment: Кажется UB. Я бы свою функцию написал.

Comment: Мне кажется, что UB. Но встречный вопрос — что вам дает выбрасывание одной переменной? Допустим на минутку, что ваш вариант корректен. Все равно значение должно где-то храниться для сравнения — так в чем выгода?

Comment: @Harry меньше кода, `std::exchange` может быть реализован быстрее

Comment: Меньше *какого* кода? Генерируемого? Не меньше. Написать свою функцию — и вызов будет очень короткий. `exchange` быстрее? А почему, собственно? Кстати, напишите свою реализацию `exchange`, которая будет возвращать не старое значение, а флаг — типа `template<class T, class U = T> bool change(T& obj, U&& new_value) { T old_value = std::move(obj); obj = std::forward<U>(new_value); return old_value != obj; }`.

Comment: *"`std::exchange` может быть реализован быстрее"* Наоборот, он скорее медленнее. Вы понимаете, что ему приходится копировать (точнее перемещать) старое значение в отдельную переменную? А вашему коду не приходится.